# Displaying Results In My View In A <UL> From My Foreach In My Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach

I am using a stored proc to get all the enteries of my 'Places' column and i want to display the results in a `<ul>` on my site but i'm struggling.

I've got the `Foreach` working and it returns all my enteries but when i try displaying my results, it only shows my last one.

I've never written a `Foreach` before to display my results.

**Code Behind**

```
namespace PaydayLunchGenerator
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {        
        public string PlaceABC;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PaydayLunchConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetPlaces", conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        PlaceABC = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Code i tried in my view**

```
<% foreach (var ABC in PlaceABC)
{ %>
     <li><%= PlaceABC %></li>
<%} %>
```

I'll be honest and i have no idea on how to write it so i took a guess at my view's `foreach`. All the data is provided from my code behind.

Comment: If you are trying to loop through `PlaceABC` then you should have a collection of items right? But in your code `PlaceABC` is a string. Also, don't try to mess up your code using complex code nuggets, use asp.net repeater control for this which is an ideal solution for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your PlaceABC is a List instead of a string, so change this:

`public string PlaceABC` to `public List<string> PlaceABC = new List<string>();`

then change

```
while (reader.Read())
      {
          PlaceABC = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
      }
```

to this:

```
   while (reader.Read())
      {
          PlaceABC.Add(reader.GetValue(1).ToString());             
      }
```

and in your view:

```
<% foreach (var ABC in PlaceABC)
{ %>
     <li><%= PlaceABC %></li>
<%} %>
```

should be

```
<% foreach (var ABC in PlaceABC)
{ %>
     <li><%= ABC %></li>
<%} %>
```

Comment: I would reccoment a `List<string>` instead of a `string[]` and use `Add` instead of specifying an index.

Comment: @BrechtBaekelandt I get an error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on the `index++;` line

Comment: @DStanley So are you saying i should try `List<string> PlaceABC`? I'm stuck on your `Add` though, not to sure how to use it. I tried `PlaceABC.Add` but it says "Cannot assign to 'Add' because it is a 'method group"

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) to see how to use `Add` properly. The reason you're  getting the error not is because the answer doesn't show how to create the array (or how to know what size it should be).  Using `List` solves the latter problem.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right @D Stanly, I actually never use arrays so i forgot a bit how they work, you indeed have to initialize them with a length, so yes using a List is better, or an ArrayList, I will update my answer, if you can markt it as answered?